# Validating phone numbers in python using RE

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to validate a phone number using Regex, using the below syntax. The number must start with 9 and has 9 digits after that. Can you please advice what can probably be wrong in this code.

```
import re
phn = "9123456789"

res = re.findall("(9)?[0-9]{9}", phn)

print (res)

O/p:
['9']
```

Answer (score 2):

`?` means "optionally." If your number *must* start with 9, you do not need `?`:

```
re.findall("9[0-9]{9}", phn)
```

Or, better:

```
re.findall(r"9\d{9}", phn)
```

Comment: Got it. Worked
Thanx for the quick help.

Comment: @BhargavMg Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped. The same applies for your previous questions as you don't seem to have accepted any of the answers for them either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a very good webside](https://regex101.com/) you might love: it makes regex easy.

Here is an extract of the website with [the solution of you problem](https://regex101.com/r/6bcpWP/1) `9[0-9]{9}`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use python library phonenumbers to validate the phone number extracted by commonregex :

```
import import commonregex
import phonenumbers

phone_list = commonregex.phone.findall(input_string)
for phone in phone_list:
    phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse(phone, None))
```

I hope it helps you.